# Google script: cannot refer to users using Session.getActiveUser()

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Google Apps Script that executes as me.
In the script, I want to know the user's email.
So I refer to the email of the user accessing my application as `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`

That's not working out at all. Google Apps Script is giving an error, saying

> Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() is NULL.

When I manually enter a dummy email instead of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, the code works perfectly

PS: The app MUST execute as me, because it needs to access my contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` return the user's email id while the app is running as you. There are some workarounds you can try

1. Ask for the user's email id explicitly.
2. Write two scripts - one which is the front end UI etc. that run as the user accessing the app (this allows Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() to return the user's email address). Have a second script that does the tasks where your contacts are accessed.
   Call the second script from the first by using doPost and doGet methods in your second script. 
   For example,

Script 1:

```
function whatever(){
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('SERVICE_URL_OF_SCRIPT_2'); 
}
```

Script 2:

```
function doGet(e){
  // code to access your contact, get parameters in e.parameters

}
```

Comment: I have:
function whatever(){
 // UI elements, handler, etc
 return app
}
 function doGet(e){
 //call e.parameter.textbox, try to retrieve Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
}
And I'm certain the documentation says Active user is whoever's currently at the keyboard, while Effective user is the one under whose authority the web app is running.

Comment: Just split the two functions across different scripts and tie them together using the UrlFetch as I suggested.

Comment: Sorry man, your answer doesn't answer my question. The script has to run as me.
Otherwise it becomes too invasive to the end user.