# anyoneCanAddSelf() Google CalendarEvent - How does user add self as guest?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Forms and Apps Script to add events to calendars.  I cannot send 1000 invites, so I'm setting anyoneCanAddSelf(true) and that is working - it gets set properly.  I'd like the users to add themselves with a "yes" rsvp and add the event to their calendars.  I also need to report on rsvp statuses.

However, I can't locate any way that users can add themselves.  The closest solution I can find is 
 [How to add add "Invite Me" link in Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235794/how-to-add-add-invite-me-link-in-google-calendar), which is a nice demo of a web app that posts to itself, but doesn't flow with my script - I can't have it post back to my admin form because it has controls to edit and delete events.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to either show an event RSVP (like you'd see with an invite) without sending invites or having a 1000 person guest list (am I missing something in the API)?
2. If I used a klugey version of the linked example above (separate cron or post to yet another form), is the user signed up automatically or do they still need to RSVP?

I'd really like this to be simple when I setup the event and not make the user click an extra three or four times.  Many of my users get confused easily.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. I want anyone in the public to add themselves as a guest. What did you end up doing in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Info on this topic is really hard to find, so I thought I'd chime in with what I learned trying to do that "invite me" link last week. I'm not sure why you can't create a new script project just for the self-invite link, but hopefully my info will help anyway.

Basically at time of writing, the feature doesn't exist, despite the anyoneCanAddSelf property of events. When a script runs as a web app, it has 2 user objects: active and effective.

If the script runs as the author (an option when you publish) the effective user is always the author, and the active user is always empty. This is purposeful for security, so this is no good.

When the script runs as a calendar subscriber, they can add themselves as a guest with

```
anyoneCanAddSelf(true) 
event.addGuest(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
```

but *only if they have modify permission* on the event and this will only add them to the guestlist, so they still have to RSVP normally. You could use the uncomfirmed guest list as implied RSVPs, but there's no way around the potential for end-user confusion.

As a side note, don't be tricked by `event.setMyStatus(CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES);` For some reason this doesn't use the active or the effective user, and instead sets the calendar itself as RSVPd to it's own event as explained better [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5336) 8/

I'm hoping to get some time to try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630955/google-script-cannot-refer-to-users-using-session-getactiveuser), but I'm not very optimistic.

HTH!

Comment: If the user is not on the calendar invite, how would they have "modify permission"? In other words, I thought "modify permission" is controlled by the "Guests can: Modify event" flag on an invite, which only affects those people *already* on the invite, leading to a catch 22.